# Microsoft.Scripting.SyntaxErrorException: 'invalid syntax'

Tags: python, c#, visual-studio, ironpython

I'm trying to run a python with C#. The purpose of the python script is just an os.walk in a directory. I'm currently using IronPython. But when I'm trying to run the c# program I'm getting this exception: [image]Microsoft.Scripting.SyntaxErrorException: 'invalid syntax'

I went to the python script and saw no syntax error. When I change my python script source code to
a simple print("hello world"), it works perfectly.
Why I'm getting this error?
Here is my C# code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using IronPython;
using IronPython.Hosting;
using Microsoft.Scripting.Hosting;


namespace TestIronPython
{
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        
        var script = @"D:\Github R\Python\Cache\Testironpython\venv\main\main.py";
        ScriptEngine engine = Python.CreateEngine();
        engine.ExecuteFile(script);
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
   

}
}
```

And here is my python code:

```
import sys
import os
from pathlib import Path

Drive_Path = Path(f"D:\Github")
for x in os.walk(Drive_Path):
print(x)
print('done')
```

Comment: Note hat indentation matters in Python; was indentation lost when formatting the question?

Comment: @KlausGütter Yes, but not in the code of my IDE(Pycharm Professional).

Answer (score 0):

I suspect the issue may be this:  `f"D:\Github"`.  I do not believe IronPython supports f-strings.